# Constructing an energy functional

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stability-theory

Suppose $U=\Omega \times (0,\infty),$ $\Omega$ is a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $u \in C^{2,1}(\overline{U})$ satisfies $u_t=\Delta u - u^3$ in $U$ with $u(x,t)=0$ on $\partial \Omega \times (0,\infty).$ Construct an energy functional and use it to show that $u(x,t) \rightarrow 0$ as $t \rightarrow \infty.$

I haven't learnt constructing such a functional. I'm studying for my preliminaries. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the $\delta$ in the equation?

Comment: My mistake. That's the Laplacian.

Comment: Do you know a way to do this in the case of the heat equation?

Comment: @Ian I do because when the equation is given in terms of (say) $u_t-ku_{xx}=0$ for $0 \leq x \leq l,~t >0$ we do have the forumula $E[u](t)=\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} [u(x,t)]^{2}~dx.$

Comment: Right. Now what is the change in $E$ over time in your nonlinear PDE?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know. I need a $u$ for the integrand. To get that I need to solve the given BVP.

Comment: Not quite. (If you could explicitly solve the IBVP then you probably wouldn't be bothering to do this more delicate analysis in the first place!) How can you write $\frac{dE}{dt}$ for the heat equation?

Comment: $\frac{d}{dt}E=\int_{0}^{l} uu_t~dx=k~\int_{0}^{l} uu_{xx}~dx$

Comment: OK. (Your limits are actually wrong, but this is not that important.) Now: 1. use integration by parts to make $\int u \Delta u dx$ into something you know is negative. 2. What happens if you substitute $u_t$ from your IBVP instead?

Comment: You mean $\frac{dE}{dt}=-2 \int_{\Omega} |\nabla u(x,t)|^2~dx \leq 0$ ?

Comment: Yes, that is the linear part. What does the nonlinear part do?

Comment: That I'm not sure. It's ok. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The intution that @Ian is driving at here, is this: You may think of the equation as a combination of the heat equation $u_t=\Delta u$ (which you already know how to handle) and $u_t=-u^3$, which is actually an ODE. You can solve the latter explicitly, but more importantly, since the RHS has the opposite sign of $u$, it will drive the value of $u$ towards zero. In particular the term $-u^3$ will also help to decrease the usual energy functional. For details, see the answer that Ian provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $E[u](t)=\int_\Omega |u(x,t)|^2 dx$ then

$$\frac{dE}{dt}=2 \int_\Omega u(x,t) u_t(x,t) dx = 2 \int_\Omega u(x,t) (\Delta u(x,t) - u(x,t)^3) dx \\
= -2 \int_\Omega |\nabla u(x,t)|^2 dx - 2 \int_\Omega u(x,t)^4 dx \leq 0$$

with equality iff $u(\cdot,t)=0$ (strictly speaking if $u(x,t)=0$ for a.e. $x$, but you have enough regularity that this just means $u(\cdot,t)=0$).

Comment: thanks again. If I ask one more question, the problem says $u(x,t) \rightarrow \infty$ as $t \rightarrow \infty,$ but what you've proved here is $u(x,t) \equiv 0.$ Should'nt the question have worded differently ?

Comment: I haven't, actually. I showed that $\frac{dE}{dt} \leq 0$ and that $\frac{dE}{dt}<0$ unless $u=0$. You now still need to show that $E \to 0$ (which is not immediate from here, it requires some estimation still) so that you can conclude that $u \to 0$.